# Not able to set an expiration date to a session cookie using express

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, web-development-server

I was trying to create a session for a client, and tried to set an expiration date for the cookie to expire after a day by -

```
const session = require('express-session')
const sessionConfig = {
    secret: 'thiswillbeupdatedinthefuture',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookies: {
        expires: Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24,
        maxAge: 1000*60*60*24,
        httpOnly: true
    }
}
app.use(session(sessionConfig))
```

I got no error executing the code, but when I inspected the web-page and saw the cookie details under the Application section, it still showed the Expires/Max-Age column for the `connect.sid` cookie to be set to `Session` instead of the expiration date I expected.
I also tried to print the cookie in console using - `console.log(req.session)` and the output was -

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

which probably means that the expiration date has still not be changed to what I expected.
Please help me understand why this problem is occurring and find a possible solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expires` attribute expects Date as an argument, so you should use: `new Date(Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24)`.

Additionally, you should not mix `Max-Age` and `Expires`.

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> If both Expires and Max-Age are set, Max-Age has precedence.

So use either `Max-Age` or `Expires`.

And I just noticed that you are using `cookies` keyword, but in the express-session docs I see `cookie` everywhere. So it looks like typo in your code.

Comment: The problem was that I was using `cookies` instead of `cookie`. Thanks for bringing up other points as well, but rest of the code unchanged works as well.